# How can I add a service account to IIS8?

Tags: service, account, iis-8

Actually I need to access to another folder at different server at the same network. I am planing to generate a kind of active directory user to work with the web server and my data server. How can I add it to my IIS 8?

I can't find any link to add access to Authentication section at IIS. 
appreciate any help.

Comment: A bit more about the Service account: In my mind a service account is a kind of active directory account that is accessible from all of servers and will be used only for specific reasons. For example we can use it for access to folder at shared folder at data server or run java when needs to access to specific area. I am sure there is a way to add this user to IIS as well then it can access to another server folders with proper permission.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution! Simple as few click!!!

you can do it with following my Guid:

1. Select Application Pool at IIS8
2. Right click on the related pool and select advanced Setting
3. Find Identity under Process Model section
4. Set your credential at Custom account section.

it is done and don't forget to recycle the application pool and restart your web services.